# Is it true that Mathematicians have a short shelf-life / peak early?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

I have always heard this claim that, out of all disciplines, Mathematicians have the shortest 'shelf-life'. More specifically, that they peak early in their twenties *(i.e. present their most important contributions / most of their work in their early twenties)* and then decline fast. As opposed to Biologists, for example, who are said to peak much later in their lives and keep contributing well into their 70s or beyond.

- How historically *(statistically?)* accurate is this claim?
- And if it is true, what would be the reason behind it? Could it be because of the decline in fluid intelligence *(pure reasoning)* that has been empirically observed to also peak in the early twenties and start declining by late twenties?

Comment: No, but the stereotype has currency among mathematicians. Just as the stereotype that men are more capable in the subject (that men are still in the majority is certainly true). Hardy's quip "*mathematics, more than any other art or science, is a young man's game*" is notorious, even though it is not born out by the facts, see e.g.  [Major mathematical advances past age fifty](https://mathoverflow.net/q/25630) and [Mathematicians who were late learners?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/3591) on MO.

Comment: On my opinion, this (wrong) impression is due to the fact that it is easier for a very young person to obtain a substantial result in mathematics, in comparison to other sciences. For this reason, there are many examples when important results are obtained by very young people.

Comment: Echoing @AlexandreEremenko's comment: indeed, to do very good things in mathematics seems to require less life experience, less human experience, than in some other sciences, not to mention humanities. Another, opposite, point is that, according to mythology, the restriction of the Fields Medal to under-40's was due to the idea that mature mathematicians do/would have insurmountable advantages over even-very-talented beginners. Perhaps someone can corroborate/debunk that point?

Comment: @paulgarrett [According to Barany](https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2018/07/25/the-forgotten-dream-of-the-fields-medal/), who did detailed research into the medal's history, the age limit did not come from Fields or deep considerations either pro or anti young age. "*In 1966, the committee decides that all of this parsing who’s recognized, who’s not, who’s well known, who’s not — it’s getting too hard. We’d better just pick an age limit... “40” doesn’t have some magical relationship to mathematical activity. That’s just the smallest round number that included all of the medalists before 1966.*"

Comment: See also his note in Nature, [The Fields Medal should return to its roots](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-00513-8):"*This idea of giving a top prize to rising stars who — by brilliance, luck and circumstance — happen to have made a major mark when relatively young is an accident of history. It is not a reflection of any special connection between maths and youth — a myth unsupported by the data*".